# How to get AngularJs route path right after domain part?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For example if I have this kind of url `localhost/About`, `localhost/Projects`, `localhost/Photography`, how can I get the value after `localhost/`, i.e `About` `Projects` `Photography`?

I have written my app.js as below:

```
angularSite.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/About', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
       // controller: 'AboutController'
      }).
      when('/Projects', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html',
        controller: 'WorkController'
      }).
      when('/Photography', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/photo.html',

      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the current path in a controller/service/directive, `$location.path()` should do it (you'll need to inject `$location`).

[Angular docs on `$location`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)